# Google Chrome search my website from URL Bar

Tags: google-chrome

If you open Google Chrome, click inside the URL bar and write: `google.com` and hit `tab`,
you'll get a: `Search Google for <enter query>`.

I tried it on my website and because I'm using javascript to process the form before sending it to an SEO friendly url, the search for my website is not working
It's redirecting me to `site.com/?question=test` instead of `site.com/search/test`

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: It's called the omnibar. You can google "adding omnibar support to your website" for some tutorials. It's really just a meta tag.

Comment: Thanks! Why not post it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the omnibar. There are some tutorials if you search Google for them. It's just a `link` tag that tells Chrome what URL to use when the user searches your site with the omnibar. The specifics are detailed in the Open Search Description (OSD).

Here is Stack Overflow's OSD:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml" />
```